# What string pattern will match $n$ contiguous characters drawn from a given alphabet?

Tags: string-manipulation

I'd like to use `StringCount` to count the number of subwords in a string that have the form `****` where `*` is designed to stand for any character in a specified set:

```
starSet = {"A","B","C"};
modifiedStringCount[string,"*****"]
```

For example:

```
string = "ABAACAWABCAA";
```

Would generate an output of `2` if `Overlaps -> FALSE` and a output of `3` is `Overlaps -> TRUE`.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
starSet = {"A", "B", "C"};
StringCount["ABAACAWABCAA", Repeated[starSet, {5}], 
            Overlaps -> False]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

#### Edit:

`Alternatives` is redundant, see the comment of [Sjoerd C. de Vries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/57/sjoerd-c-de-vries) below. Thanks ;)

Comment: I was trying to find a duplicate but I've failed :/

Comment: I don't think Alternatives is necessary here. A list of patterns is already interpreted as alternatives. See under Details at the [StringExpression page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringExpression.html?q=StringExpression&lang=en).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries +1 :) I was not aware of that :)

Comment: Not everyone is aware of `Repeated`. Just leave it so.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Ok, will stay then.